# Webpack NodeJS API Optimize Minimize

Tags: webpack, webpack-2

How can I add the --optimize-minize webpack flag when using NodeJS API?

In the documentation, there is no way to pass parameters other than the Webpack config. I'm trying to replicate the behavior configuring the UglifyJSPlugin, but the chunks are always bigger than the ones using --optimize-minimize.

Any suggestions. I'm using webpack@3.4.1

Comment: Can you post you webpack config. If the chunks are bigger then I have a feeling that UglifyJS is not working correctly

Comment: OP asks what is the name of the needed option. If you have no idea how to turn that option on, it's obvious why it doesn't work.